# angular end to end template testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, e2e-testing

I am really new to angular and testing. I am actually creating my first e2e test and would need some guidance.
I have a listing.component.html something like this-

```
<md-list>
<div *ngIf="items | async as items; else loading">
    <ng-container *ngIf="items.length; else noItems">
        <div class="item-row" *ngFor="let item of items | search:'LoanNumber,Borrower_LastName,Borrower_FirstName':searchTerm" [class.selected]="selectedItemId === item.ORDER_ID" >
          <list-item [item]="item"></list-item>
          <div *ngIf="selectedItem|async as itemData">
            <list-item-details [data]="itemData" *ngIf="selectedItemId === item.ORDER_ID"></list-item-details>
          </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #noItems>No Items!</ng-template>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>loading animation...</ng-template>
</md-list>
```

I want to create a test case where I check if my "No Items!" is displayed in case my items array is empty. 
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: If you want to do E2E testing in your Angular app, then Protractor is a great tool to do that. It is easy to use and has great documentation. https://www.protractortest.org/#/

Comment: @Narm okay. thanks. I will look into it.